# How to use g2o framework for Graph Optimization (SLAM) on windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a graph slam project and i want to use g2o framework (https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o) de develop the application using visual studio 2010. This framework works primarly on linux but it can be used for windows as well.

Could any one tell me how to use with visual studio

Thank you,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in Windows because all requirements have a port to Visual Studio.

- cmake             http://www.cmake.org/
- Eigen3            http://eigen.tuxfamily.org
- suitesparse       http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/
- Qt4               http://qt.nokia.com/
- libQGLViewer      http://www.libqglviewer.com/

> Our primary development platform is Linux. Experimental support for
>   Mac OS X and Windows (MinGW or MSVC). We recommend a so-called out of
>   source build which can be achieved by the following command sequence.[(1)](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o)

Use [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) to build it.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser, i installed the obove soft, then i downloded the g2omaster folder as a zip file. I used cmake like this : i set the source code g2omaster and added a new folder "build" for the generated files. here what i got

Comment: Disabling memory alignment for MSVC8
Compiling on Windows
Compiling with MSVC
Could NOT find CHOLMOD (missing:  CHOLMOD_INCLUDE_DIR CHOLMOD_LIBRARIES) 
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.

Comment: Try OpenMP C flag = [/openmp]
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
Try OpenMP C flag = [-Qopenmp]
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
Try OpenMP C flag = [-openmp]
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
Try OpenMP C flag = [ ]
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
Try OpenMP C flag = [-xopenmp]

Comment: Could NOT find Qt4 (missing:  QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY QT_QTXML_INCLUDE_DIR

Comment: QT_QTXML_LIBRARY QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find QGLVIEWER (missing:  QGLVIEWER_LIBRARY) 
Compiling g2o apps
Compiling g2o examples
Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing:  EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN3_VERSION_OK) (Required is at least version "2.91.0")
Configuring done

Answer (score 0):

I remember having some issues with building g2o on Windows. But the CMake should work well. Just configure, generate, and you can open the solution with Visual Studio and build. If it says "Configuring Done", it should compile. Eigen3 is sometimes tough to find for CMake, as their find script is not officially distributed with CMake (yet).

You can run (assuming you are in `g2o/trunk/build` folder, hence `..`):

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/path/to/a/dir/containing_the_FindEigen3.cmake_file/
```

There are also other libraries that solve graph problems efficiently, such as [SLAM++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/slam-plus-plus/), [iSAM](http://people.csail.mit.edu/kaess/isam/) or [GTSAM](http://borg.cc.gatech.edu/), they compile on Windows with less problems.